# When use JOIN how to leave results blank if columns not exist, and how to use CASE WHEN based on existence of a column

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * ,
    CASE eventid
        WHEN NOT NULL THEN 'YES'
        WHEN NULL THEN 'NO'
        END AS suspicious
FROM 
account_black b
JOIN
account_all a
ON LEFT(user_id,14) <> LEFT(userid,14)
```

Problem 1: I am joining two tables, and wish to leave the result value blank in some columns if either table doesn't have those columns. However, the result table auto-fills blanks with values from other rows.

Problem 2: I want to use CASE and WHEN to mark rows based on the existence of a column in their original tables, but I failed and get NULL. In this case, I want to have 'Yes' if the original table has value in eventid column, 'no' if from table does not have the column.

PS: I want to avoid using UNION or UNION ALL in this case but use JOIN instead.

account_black description:

[image: account_black]

account_all description:

[image: account_all]

Actual Result:
[image: result table]
Expected Result:
[image: Expected table]

Comment: Please add representative sample data and desired outcome as text.

Comment: @P.Salmon Sorry for being vague, I have added more information.